# Saving manually edited iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Ok, so I'm the kind of person that changes IPTABLES by editing /etc/sysconfig/iptables, what's the way to make them save so that someone accidentally using "iptables save" doesn't overwrite them?

Comment: Don't give root privileges to idiots? Otherwise making the file read-only should work.

Comment: That works, I also did iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Answer (score 0):

HBruijn is right.

This is not a technical problem - it's a people problem. If those with root access are doing stupid things, then revoke their access.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. By putting rules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` you are basically saving them. IF there are other scripts on your system that would cause `iptables-save` to write rules there, you'll need to modify those scripts. If you have other admins or something, make it a policy that modifications to the firewall must be made in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. If you're "in charge" of the box then that should be your prerogative.

If users (!!) are editing the firewall and do the wrong thing, it's your duty to correct their actions or revoke their privileges.